# repetition "{}" on fly for regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a function that compare a value with a regex to see if matches. The problem is that I have quite a many regex that are similar with just one difference which the range `{}` e.g.  `^[a-z]{0,500}$` & `^[a-z]{0,200}$` are similar regex with just a diff of range/repetition. I am trying to solve that problem of how to deal with these regex with one function. So far I have written that function. But I think there must be some option that is much better than what I have done below. It should also be able to deal if no max or min is specified as well.

```
def check(value, min=None, max=None):
    regex = "^[a-z]"+"{"+min+","+max+"}$"
    r= re.compile(regex)
    if r.match(value):
        return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: Then why don't you directly use `^[a-z]{0,500}$` ?

Comment: Building a RegExp with strings always feels like building SQL with string concatenation which sounds _really_ scary, however in your specific case, that seems acceptable (don't you want/need to cast min and max to strings using `str()` first though?) Also, why is `value` an optional parameter?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : That value thing is just a mistake. I have corrected it now. and min and max are already been passed as string. But good point that they should be casted here in the function.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV : Because it depends on specific type of some require  200 max and some 500 max.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: That was one another mistake. I wanted to chage value from optional to required but accidentally removed all. I dont know what I was thinking :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `min="0"` and `max=""` instead (that way, they will construct valid ranges if left unspecified).

Also, don't do `if condition: return True` etc. - just return the match object - it will evaluate to `True` if there is a match (and you can do stuff with it later if you want to).

Further, no need to compile the regex if you're only using it once.

```
def check(value, min="0", max=""):
    regex = "[a-z]{" + min + "," + max + "}$"
    return re.match(regex, value)
```

Also, I've removed the `^` because it's implicit in `re.match()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about ^ . So there is no way to make neater. I thought perhaps `re` might have some option of dealing with these kind of situation. Anyways thanks for helping.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum :  thanks for reminding that. I guess I am having a bad day and forgetting lot of things.